# Odd $_SESSION contents

Tags: sessions

I have a page in Drupal from which I want to be able to read the $_SESSION data to determine the userid and their assigned role. As an exploration I attempted to print to the page the contents of $_SESSION so that I could see what was being stored and what the keys were to retrieve these values.

When I attempt to print to the page using `echo print_r($_SESSION);`, instead of a set of reasonable session data, I instead get only this:

`Array ( [batches] => Array ( [1] => 1 ) )`

I had a bit of a Google around to see if I was doing something wrong, and I came across [the documentation for session.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/7), which says:

> These functions should not be called directly. Session data should instead be accessed via the $_SESSION superglobal.

So it seems that, while Drupal wants me to use $_SESSION to retrieve the session data, I can't do this because my $_SESSION data has only this odd pair of nested one-element arrays that store only the number 1.

I also came across some reports that not having the uid 0 in your users table can cause similar issues, so I have checked the users table and I do indeed have user 0.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you accessing the session to determine the userid and their assigned role? This is a case where the Drupal APIs should suffice.  global $user and $user->roles has the information you need.

Comment: I came across some talk of $user but upon attempting to read that variable/object it doesn't exist, so I resorted to trying to pull a userid out of session data (a method I've used previously in another system, albeit not related to drupal, that sideloaded session data to check the userid).

Comment: Ugh.  Now I see what I did.  I didn't realise I needed to call 'global $user' before attempting to access it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_SESSION` variable contains values set by Drupal; in your case, `$_SESSION['batches']` is the value set by the [Batch API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7). Drupal, although, doesn't use the session to store the user ID; that value is stored in the `$user` global variable, as cilefen correctly said in his comment.

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
$roles = $user->roles;
```

Keep in mind that the `$user` global variable doesn't contain a fully-loaded user object; to get that, you need to use the following code.

```
$account = user_uid_optional_load();
```

`$account` will contain every field associated with the user entity, and any property attached to the user object from third-party modules.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I had come across someone mentioning using $user but I didn't understand that I had to call 'global $user' in order to access it, so it didn't work out for me, which led me down the path of attempting to read the session data to get a userid with which to query the database (a method I've used before when I had to build some pages to sit alongside an existing installation of another (not drupal) system and dip into its database to grab things).

Now I can start building this thing properly.  Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes we tend to leave implicit some details like that. `:D`